# How can I specify a single .config file for multiple EXE projects in .NET

Tags: .net, configuration

I have a project that I am breaking up into multiple .exe projects. I still plan on publishing them, using click once, into the same location at the same time, and I would like to use the same config file.

I have added the `app.config` to each project using the "Add link" option in Visual Studio, which is great for debugging, but in production, when I compile each exe project, the `app.config` is not copied into the "master project"'s bin folder.

example:

`master.exe` with `master.exe.config`

`master.exe` may launch `order.exe` based on user settings
`master.exe` may launch `returns.exe` based on user settings

master, order, and returns will all reside in the same folder, and should share a single config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, not with the default CLR host.  You could write a custom host that uses a different AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile to initialize the primary AppDomain.  But you'd surely don't want that pursue that, C++ and COM skillz required.

Using a lot of EXEs is pretty unusual.  Most anything a EXE can do, a Thread can do as well.  Other than preventing the main app from going down when it crashes with an unhandled exception.  Stuffing the config in a separate xml file is probably the quickest solution.

Comment: Thats what I figured, but I wanted to ask to be sure. Sometimes there are hidden gems that I'm not aware of.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that if you want to do this it might be better to just read/write to the config file via the normal XML classes.